# Can't assign new value of object's parameter

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my problem. I can't assign new value of parameter after comparison of another object's parameters with database object's parameters. I need to assign new value of ***test_car.make*** or ***make***. It seems, that XML code is fine, so the problem should be in that code.
Here is my code:

```
package com.j.caradvisor;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.j.models.Car;

public class Result extends AppCompatActivity {

    int i=0;
    int doors;
    String make;
    String model;
    String layout;
    String trunk;
    String gearbox;
    int price;
    int expeople;
    Car test_car = new Car(1, "testmake", "testmodel", "test_layuot", "testtrunk", "testgearbox", 1, 1);
    String final_car=make+""+model;
    TextView resultt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        resultt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        test_car = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("test_car");
        doors = test_car.getDoors();
        make = test_car.getMake();
        model = test_car.getModel();
        trunk = test_car.getTrunk();
        gearbox = test_car.getGearbox();
        price = test_car.getPrice();
        expeople = test_car.getExpeople();
        this.getPackageName();
        //resultt.setText(final_car);
    }
    public void data(View view) {
        Car[] car;
        car = new  Car[12];
        car[0] = new Car(4, "Volkswagen", "Passat", "4 door saloon", "Spacious", "Both", 25000, 5);
        car[1] = new Car(2, "Mazda", "MX-5", "Roadster", "Small", "Both", 20000, 2);
        car[2] = new Car(2, "BMW", "2 series", "2 door coupe", "Spacious", "Both", 20000, 4);
        car[3] = new Car(3, "Volkswagen", "Golf", "3 door hatchback", "Spacious", "Both", 20000, 4);
        car[4] = new Car(5, "Peugeot", "308", "5 door hatchback", "Spacious", "Both", 20000, 5);
        car[5] = new Car(5, "Peugeot","508","Estate", "Spacious", "Both", 25000, 5);
        car[6] = new Car(5, "Ford", "S-Max", "Minivan", "Spacious", "Both", 28000,7);
        car[7] = new Car(5, "Ford", "Transit", "Van", "Spacious", "Manual", 20000, 9);
        car[8] = new Car(3, "Jeep", "Wrangler", "3 door SUV", "Spacious", "Automatic", 40000, 4);
        car[9] = new Car(5, "KIA", "Sportage", "5 door SUV", "Spacious", "Both", 25000, 5);
        car[10] = new Car(4, "Audi", "A7", "4 door coupe", "Spacious", "Both", 60000, 4);
        car[11] = new Car(5, "Peugeot", "208", "5 door hatchback", "Small", "Both", 14000, 5);
        for (Car aCar : car) {
            if ((test_car.getDoors() == aCar.getDoors())
                    && (test_car.getLayout().equals(aCar.getLayout()))
                    && (test_car.getTrunk().equals(aCar.getTrunk()))
                    && (test_car.getGearbox().equals(aCar.getGearbox()))
                    && (test_car.getPrice() <= aCar.getPrice())
                    && (test_car.getExpeople() <= aCar.getExpeople())) {

                test_car.setMake(aCar.getMake());
                make = test_car.getMake();
                //model=car[i].getModel();
                //test_car.setMake(make);
                //test_car.setModel(model);
                //resultt.setText(make);
                //resultt.setText(test_car.getMake());
            }
        }
        //resultt.setText(test_car.getMake());
        resultt.setText(make);
    }

    public void map_search(View view) {
        String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +test_car.getMake();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: and what actual problem do you have? is Car a mutable type?

Comment: Small observation: "test_layout" is spelt incorrectly in the `test_car` instantiation; the "o" and "u" need to switch positions.

Comment: Charles,thanks, but it doesn't have any effect on general code

Comment: Stultuske, I've declared all setters and getters in specialized class. So it's mutable. The problem is in assigning of **make** parameter from array's object to String **make** or to **test_car.set.make**. It simply doesn't do the assignment and returns default value *testmake*

Answer (score 0):

> `if ((test_car.getDoors() == aCar.getDoors())`

It seems to always be returning false since your test car is set to 1 (I am assuming car[0] is the doors) so

> ```
> test_car.setMake(aCar.getMake());
> make = test_car.getMake();`
> ```

Never runs, this also depends on what you're giving as the intents ParcableExtra

> `test_car = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("test_car");`

Comment: Everything is parceled well from previous activity, I've tested it. Car[0] is a first object of Car Array. The problem is in comparison of "test_car's" and car[i]" parameters

Comment: So with your test car, you want to change the make (cars[1]) if it has the same number of doors, same trunk, layout and gearbox (cars[0],cars[3],cars[4],cars[5]) as well as a price and expected number of people (cars[6],cars[7]) less than or equal to that of the test, right?